# Order the result by best match on other field

Tags: elasticsearch

Nowdays I am learning Elasticsearch and I have a lot of questions.

The most immediate question that arises is how to sort by the best match of a field (unfiltered).

I have the following set of data:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Smith",
    "categories": ["1", "2"]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "John Smith",
    "categories": ["2", "3"]
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "categories": ["2", "4"]
}
```

I want to search by `name` and in case the result will be the same I would like to order by best match on `categories`.

My current query only filters by `name`:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "query_string": {
                                "query": "*John Smith*",
                                "fields": ["name"],
                                "default_operator": "and",
                                "boost": 10
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "name": {
                                    "query": "John Smith",
                                    "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                                    "operator": "and"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case the result will be two hits (`"id": 1` & `"id": 2`) but I would like order by `categories`. For example, if I also asked for `"categories": ["3", "4"]`, the first result would be the record with `"id": 2` because this record has a category (`3`) that matches.

How can I modify my query to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, although I must say this question is more about search result relevance than ordering (sorting).

To achieve your goal you may add a `should` clause next to your `must` part of the [`bool` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-bool-query.html):

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "query_string": {
                                "query": "*John Smith*",
                                "fields": ["name"],
                                "default_operator": "and",
                                "boost": 10
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "name": {
                                    "query": "John Smith",
                                    "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                                    "operator": "and"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "should": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "categories": [
                    "3",
                    "4"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This happens because `should` in this case [only affects the score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-bool-query.html), that means brings the result that matched extra conditions higher:

> If the `bool` query is in a query context and has a `must` or `filter`
>   clause then a document will match the `bool` query even if none of the
>   `should` queries match. In this case these clauses are only used to
>   influence the score.

You can find some more information about relevance score [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-intro.html).

Hope that helps!